# Execute event before its natural behaviour

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to execute javascript-event *before* it's natural behaviour?

For example, using the code below, if you press `/` key on your keyboard, this character will be immediately printed in the input field, and after 2 seconds, the alert will be showed. That's obviuos.

But is there a way to make alert showed *before* the `/` is printed?

```
<input></input>

<script>
document.querySelector("input").focus();

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) { if (e.keyCode === 191) { myFunc(e); } });
function myFunc(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hello!");
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `input` is a void element and does not accepts a closing `</input>` tag.

Comment: FYI: note than on my keyboard `/` keyCodes are: `111` and `shiftKey+55`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unified solution for all inputted characters  on `keypress` event:

```
addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  var val = e.which || e.keyCode;
  e.preventDefault();
  myFunc(e.target, val);
});

function myFunc(target, val) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hello!");
    target.value = String.fromCharCode(val);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - its a bit of a hack

```js
document.querySelector("input").focus();

addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  //debugger;
  if (e.keyCode === 191) {
    e.target.value = "";
    myFunc(e, e.target);
  }
});

function myFunc(e, t) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hello!");
    t.value = "/";
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<input></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe is actually the default, as demonstrated here:

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test">
```

If you cancel a `keydown` event, the key is not printed. Therefore the code was executed before its default action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
function myFunc(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hello!");
    }, 2000);
}
```

to

```
function myFunc(e) {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```